# What two whole numbers result in a specified percentage?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking at voting results between two candidates (A and B) on a website that updates as votes are added.  Each time I refresh, you can only see the percentage of the vote each had. For example, here are the latest results of a few different time of the day points:
\begin{array}{ccccc}
& 10:00 & 10:05 & 10:10 & 10:15 \\
A & 52.33\% & 52.35\% & 52.36\% & 52.51\% \\ 
B & 47.67\% & 47.65\% & 47.64\% & 47.49\%
\end{array}
What I want to know is what are the likely actual votes at these times for A and B, based on these percentages?

Comment: It's an interesting question. However, considering all these percentages are not exactly what they look like because they were rounded to two decimals, this seems to be difficult to do. Maybe set up some simultaneous inequalities?

Comment: Thank you zipirovich,

Comment: Thank you zipirovich,

I apologize that I am just a layman when it comes to math. I'm not familiar with techniques beyond the simplest formulas.  I read a bit on simultaneous inequalities but I'm not sure how to apply them.  I figured there may be a simple way that I was unaware of.  I understand that the percentages are rounded, which makes it difficult.  
I tried my own method of using a spreadsheet and tried to guess at the votes to see what percentage they resulted in.  Here is what I came up with:

A 1559 1560 1561 1570 1580

B 2979 2980 2981 2990 3000

Comment: Impossible without any further info. Do you have even the slightest estimation of how many people voted in total?

Comment: I really don't know about how many in total.  That was what I was trying to determine.  BTW, my estimation above was incorrectly stated for B.  The B row is my estimation of the total.  So at 10:00 it may be 1559 out of a total of 2979.  That makes it 52.33%.  The count for B would actually be 1420 at each time, as I was guessing that there was no change in votes for B. Maybe not a good assumption but the percentages were going up.
This was an online vote from a radio station contest. Certainly not important, but I love to work on problems of any kind.  OK well I thought I would ask. Thanks.